# HomeLink not opening garage door in the mornings

Tags: nissan

I have a 2011 Nissan Murano and am currently experiencing the following situation that started about two weeks ago:

I am not able to use the in-built programmed HomeLink garage door opener in the mornings to close my garage door when leaving.  I *am* able to open/close the garage door using the same remote when returning later in the day (mid-morning to any time in the afternoon).

I was able to do this without fail since I bought the car two months ago.

The only thing that has recently changed is the weather in the area, I am in North Texas.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any reason for this to occur, but here's a wild guess: your battery is dying.

When your car sits overnight, the voltage drops enough to reduce the range of the transmitter.  In the evening, after a long drive, the battery is fully charged and so it works.

In order to eliminate this option, try putting a trickle charger on the car overnight, and see if it works the next morning.

Comment: I like the wild guess, but since this vehicle is 2 months old I would be surprised if it is the battery, plus the car is running so there should be plenty of power generated by the alternator.

Comment: @jzd: I can't disagree with you, but I can't think of any other possible cause.  And the battery could be defective.